# Background Task Taking 100% CPU and draining battery

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background

I am working on an enterprise application that has to report information consistently on a timed basis, especially when the app is in the background.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     //stuff
     UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

     //create new uiBackgroundTask
     bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     }];
     //and create new timer with async call:
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     //run function methodRunAfterBackground
     timerOne = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:100 target:self selector:@selector(refreshInactiveTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     timerTwo = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(postActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerOne forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerTwo forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
     });
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)applicationq {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    [timerOne invalidate];
    [timerTwo invalidate];
}

-(void)refreshInactiveTimer {  //this function plays a short inaudible sound which refreshes the background timer
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utter = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"up"];
    [utter setVolume:0.0];
    [synth speakUtterance:utter];
}

-(void)postActivity {
    //this function makes a NSURLRequest that posts small data back to server side
}
```

The code works as intended, but the problem is it is taking 100% CPU (according to the profiler). I do notice that the battery seems to drain quickly too when I test while unplugged, so the CPU is definitely chugging away. Perhaps I am missing something small here.

Note: yes I know this is bad practice, and Apple would reject an app using such methods. However as I mentioned this is an enterprise application that will never be on the App Store and never distributed to the general public.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think that timers don't function as expected when the app is in the background; I'm pretty sure they fire immediately.

Comment: I can confirm that they are firing at the expected intervals, indefinitely, as per server logs and debug logs.

Comment: This is working because you are mis using the plays audio mode for background running. Be aware that apple might not allow this misuse of this background mode is such a way. It will drain battery because that is what you want it to do. You might want to look at an other solutions, most of the time there is not need for the app to keep running in the background. Enterprise app can also use push notification and those can be silent since iOS 7 to allow you to update things.

Comment: I understand fully what the code does and is expected to do, and as I mentioned this is for an enterprise (internal) application. I have tried using background fetch (application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler) to the interval of UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum; but through doing this the posting of the information is completely sporadic and not often enough.

Comment: It's just strange because its a timer that executes once every 100 seconds (in this example) that utters a short word. Why the CPU is constantly cranked to 90-100% even when not executing either of these events is beyond me.